# Library to read and write an XML-based configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Can anyone give me information on available XML libraries. I would like a library which makes reading and writing XML as easy as possible, especially XML-based configuration files.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not used the .NET native, built-in configuration system? It lives in `System.Configuration`, it's extensible, it's XML based..... why reinvent the wheel yet again??

Answer (score 3):

you could use linq to xml if you need something generic.  if you need something specfically to read config files, use the built in configuration classes. MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

System.XML

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3y47afh(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use .NETs configuration section. Its XML based and flexible.
Here is a VS plugin for generating configuration sections. http://csd.codeplex.com/

I really recommend that you use configuration sections because it's standard. WCF, Log4Net, NLog, Castle Windsor, Microsoft Enterprise Library, etc uses it

Answer (score 0):

Even in Microsoft VS2019 Settings designer breaks on handling as simple as type List
It has not been a friendly experience for the programmer nor for the end-user.

You may want to look at the following, it looks simple to use...

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194029/XML-Generic-File-writing-and-loading-library